# SQLite JDBC on OS X stores and retrieves empty byte array in BLOB as null

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, null, arrays, is-empty

I'm pretty amazed, that I couldn't find anything about this on google.

I use Sqlite jdbc 3.7.2 in my application. On Windows, when I store an empty byte array in a BLOB field, the value in the SQLite column is empty. If I do the same on MacOS it is NULL.

On MacOS I now get a lot of NullPointerExceptions because of null-values instead of empty byte arrays returned from the DB.

The only similar issue i found was in [a .NET sqlite implementation](https://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/issues/detail?id=149)

Does anyone experience the same issue? And is there a easy way to change it?

Here is the Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable(uid INTEGER, aNum INTEGER,  bNum INTEGER, aText TEXT, cNum INTEGER, dNum INTEGER, data BLOB, mask BLOB, bdata BLOB, PRIMARY KEY(uid, aNum, bNum, aText))
```

Here is the statement for the insert:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

In Java I do this to store the data in sqlite:

```
  String query="INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  PreparedStatement ret = this._connection.prepareStatement(query)
  preparedStatement.setInt(1, 123);
        //...
        preparedStatement.setBytes(7, new byte[0]);
        preparedStatement.setBytes(8, new byte[]{(byte)1,(byte)2});
        preparedStatement.setBytes(9, new byte[]{(byte)2,(byte)3});

        preparedStatement.execute();
```

and this to retrieve it:
...

```
final byte[] data = resSet.getBytes(7);
```

...

now data is null, instead of an empty byte array, but only on OS X.
Thanks

Comment: Show the code that stores the empty byte array.

Comment: @CL. I added the code as you requested

Comment: `[empty byte array here]` is not valid Java.

Comment: @CL. ;-) here you go. I even commented the "..." for your

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT typeof(data) FROM MyTable WHERE uid = 123`? Are you executing that Java code on OS X?

Comment: @CL. I got the DB files from a co-worker who uses our software on an apple device. After doing some basic steps in the software he gets nullpointer exceptions. If I do the exact same steps on a windows machine, it works well. Looking into the DB files with the SQLite Database Browser shows, that empty bytes are persisted as null on OSX but as blob on Windows. To answer your question: The output of your query on SQLite Database Browser running on Windows is null if I use the DB file of my co-worker, but is blob if I use my own db files, which were created on Windows. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: What JVMs and SQLite drivers are you using on Windows and OS X? (This looks like a bug in the latter.)

Comment: @CL. I'm using sqlite jdbc 3.7.2 from here: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads. Also tried with 3.8.5 pre1 with the same result. Java version on OS X is 1.8.0_11-b12.

Comment: Created a ticket here: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issue/149/empty-byte-arrays-are-stored-as-null-in